Groom: hair cards not following strands during UE animation
I have created a groom component on my character but for some reason the hair cards don’t animate the same way the strands do. The video below shows some of the dark long hair following the trunk which is incorrect however the strands don’t do this.
https://youtu.be/DEd8iqbpH4s
I imported both the strands (alembic file) and the hair cards (static mesh fbx file) from Blender. There are no weighted vertex on the trunk for the dark hair. I have other groom components on this character and they are working fine.
I have not received a reply to this on the UE website so I thought I'd try here.

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
